# Reduce opacity of nodes in d3 process map when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am new to d3, I have a doubt on how to reduce the opacity(I want nodes to be transparent) so the when a node is been hovered it will highlight immediate parents and childs,**other nodes needs to be seen as well may be little more transparent** than which is showed in the below link,

http://nylen.tv/d3-process-map/graph.php

Also I have referenced the below link which says which are classed or not classed,

https://github.com/nylen/d3-process-map/issues/3

highlishted(object) -> which classifies nodes which are to be highlighted or which are not.

But I have to show the other nodes too may be reduced opactiy.

What changes has to be done to achieve this.

P.S: I have tried seeing d3.v3.min.js to look for opacity behavior.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to create a function that, when passed a node, will fade out unrelated nodes. You can use `d3.select(this).style("opacity", <someNumber>)` to change the opacity of an object. When passed an object, go through the list of links and find all those objects which are connected to it. Push these to an array and change their opacity accordingly. Then, recurse through the array using the same function, which will highlight the children's children. Recurse as many times as the number of level of children you want (some sort of counter, e.g. `highlightNode(node, count)`).

Comment: I have changed the opacity in css itself. Thanks for the reply though.